# Switching between two fixed fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I have this activity where I run an asynctask that gathers a series of data. This data can be represented in several ways, for the sake of simplicity let's say there's two ways. I want the user to be able to switch between these two representations (listview and graphical view).

So I created a FragmentActivity with my ListFragment and my GraphicFragment.

How do you switch between these two so that user can go back and forth?  I tried using replace but then the previous fragment gets destroyed which is not of my interest since its reference has the data passed by my Activity. (i.e. I don't want to recreate the fragment each times the user switches between views).

I also tried hiding and showing but I can't get it to work, one of the fragments is not showing.

Also, when I rotate I guess the fragments get destroyed because I get a nullpointerexception when trying to access them.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.analyzingProgress);

    // However, if we're being restored from a previous state, then don't
    // create the fragment again (please)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        firstFragment = new DirListFragment();
        secondFragment = new GraphViewFragment();

                         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment).commit();


        fragments= new ArrayList<IFragment>();
        fragments.add(firstFragment);
        fragments.add(secondFragment);
    }
}


    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.listView){

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        /*transaction.hide(secondFragment);         
        transaction.show(firstFragment);*/
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.graph){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        /*transaction.hide(firstFragment);
        transaction.show(secondFragment);*/
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem comes when I try to access the fragment fields to update their data:

```
     for(IMyFragment frag: fragments){
        frag.updateData(data);
    }
```

I get a NullPointerException after rotating the screen.

Also when switching fragmenents, their data is not updated (i.e. I start with list fragment, it's showing the proper data, then switch to graphic, no data is shown, switch back to list, no data again.)

Comment: You should really add some code so people will be able to help you better.  If you don't want the fragment to get destroyed, call `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreate` of the fragment. Then use `replace` in your activity.

Comment: I posted my oncreate function and the part of the code where i switch fragments

Comment: You should review the fragment lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating, this is where your issue is coming in to effect.  When you rotate the screen, the activity is destroyed and recreated, which in turn destroys the fragments.  If you set `setRetainInstance(true);` in your fragments, all of the information (variables) will still have values, but you will need to recreate the views because they will be destroyed.

Comment: I will have a look at that, but I tried using setRetainIntsance and my firstFragment and secondFragment fields are nulled when rotating the screen.

Comment: `setRetainInstance` doesn't help you, because your fields `firstFragment` etc are in your `activity` - which is destroyed and recreated - its fields are now null. The fragments still EXIST, but you need to find them. You need to add code like this to activity's onCreate: `FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    firstFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG);` More details in http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: ... Also, I think `replace` destroys the replaced fragment. Investigate `show` / `hide` more - something must have been wrong with your code. Or perhaps FragmentTransaction.`attach`/`detach`.

Answer (score 2):

If the fields are null when using `setRetainInstance(true);`, then you are recreating them (the fragments) in your activity. Make sure you are setting something in `onSaveInstanceState()` in your activity so in `onCreate()`, `savedInstanceState` will not be null, it can even be an empty bundle or useless variable, ex:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outstate);
    outstate.putBoolean("stateChanged", true);
}
```

Just make sure you call super before adding your arguments.

On another note, I personally have never stored my fragments in an array. I use a `FrameLayout` as a fragment container in my activities, just like you, and if I need to update something I just call: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).setWhatINeed();` This way I always get the visible fragment.

Let me know how the update goes and I'll update this post with any information I can.

Comment: Tried that but no joy. The reason I do it in an array is because those fragments are observers for the main activity, so when new data arrives they all get notified at the same time.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having now? Still the same as before? Few questions: 1) Did you check to make sure `savedInstanceState` is not null on orientation change (i.e. putting a `log.d` after `if(savedInstanceState==null)`? 2) Have you removed the `addToBackStack(null)` calls? You may be getting a nullpointer because you are adding your local instance of first/secondFragment to the backstack and then trying to update it, which I don't beleive is possible (cannot update items on the stack)

Comment: @MichelReap - instead of putting the fragments in an array, create them with tags, and put the tags in an array. Then you can always get the current instances of them using `findFragmentByTag` - no more worries about obsolete references after configuration change or other interruption to your app.